# Combine data aquired in different order each time

Tags: matlab, loops

So I have some data from an iPad app that creates a cell array called `subj`, such that in `subj` I can access results from my iPad game. I have 40 peoples' results. If I type `subj{1}.correct` it gives me the results of the 30 questions- 1 or 0 if they got it right/wrong, a `1 x 30` matrix, for subject 1. if I type `subj{1}.stimulus` it tells what questions they were presented. There are 30 questions total but each person received them in a random order. How do I get 1 matrix with subject number, their results and all sorted so they are in order by question#?

This code works if I manually change the subj number every time, so how do I loop this for all 40 participants?

```
  C1 = subj{1}.correct
  C1 = C1'
  S1 = subj{1}.stimulus 
  S1 = S1'
  S1 = sort(S1)
  A1 = table(C1,S1);
 %count, n, subj - will be in workspace
```

Here is what I attempted for the loop but it is not working :(

```
for n = 1:40;
    A{n} = subj{n}.correct
    B{n} = A{n}'
    C{n} = subj{n}.stimulus 
    D{n} = C{n}'
    E{n} = table(B{n},D{n})
end
```

This is one error it said:

> Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate issue with your code above is that you must have a variable named either `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, or `E` in your workspace already and so the assignment is failing. To be sure this doesn't happen you could pre-allocate these variables before the loop

```
A = cell(size(subj));
```

What I would instead though is to first get a list of all stimuli using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) on the first subject

```
stimuli = unique(subj{1}.stimulus);
```

We can use this as a "reference order" of the stimuli and make sure that all other subjects are sorted in this order.

I would then pre-allocate your results matrix and fill it in with a simple loop in which we use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to figure out which stimulus is listed where (the [second output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html#outputarg_Locb) gives us this index) and then use that to reorder the `correct` field. The resulting matrix is going to be `nSubjects x nStimuli` and the order of the stimuli is  the same as `stimuli` above.

```
results = false(numel(subj), numel(stimuli));

for k = 1:numel(subj)
    [~, inds] = ismember(subj{k}.stimulus, stimuli);
    results(k,:) = subj{k}.correct(inds);
end
```

If you want the output to be in a `table`, you could use `array2table` to make the conversion

```
T = array2table(results, 'VariableNames', stimuli);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So do I just run all those things you sent? Why does the stimuli part have subj{1}? Also I ran this and received this error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.

Comment: @user3290443 Are you sure that all users always answer *all* questions?

Comment: Well you completely changed my code and I have no clue whats going on anymore -- could you use a little more help -- I thought I was close since it worked on individual trials but your code uses so many things I have never seen before, I am just a beginner

Comment: @user3290443 Well the error is coming from the fact that all subjects' `stimulus` vector doesn't contain the same values. Based on your question I assumed that everyone would have the same stimuli. Is that not a valid assumption? What part explicitly do you not understand? The general idea is that I first get a list of all `stimuli` (using subject 1 as a reference) and then use those to sort all of the others.

Comment: They do all get the same stimulus but in a different order, so subj1 gets a totally different order of the same stimuli than subj2. However, your code addressed that so I am just not sure why its throwing the error? Is it because the stimulus is a different order every time?

Comment: @user3290443 My code deals with the ordering. I use `ismember` to find each `stimulus` value in the `stimuli` vector and get it's corresponding index (`inds`) so that I can use that to re-arrange the values in the `correct` field. What datatype are the `stimulus` variables? Have you double checked to see that they are all the same and that every person had every stimulus?